# Downloading image doesn't work: NodeJS

Tags: node.js, image, download

I've written a little function in Node for downloading an image from a server and saving it on my server, but it doesn't work. The image file is created, but it seems to be corrupt, here's the function:

```
function d() {
    var data = [
        {
            img: "http://wow.zamimg.com/images/hearthstone/cards/enus/original/OG_134.png",
            cardId: "yogg"
        },
        {
            img: "http://wow.zamimg.com/images/hearthstone/cards/enus/original/HERO_07.png",
            cardId: "nzoth"
        }
    ];
    for(var card of data) {
        if("img" in card) {
            var img = require('fs').createWriteStream("./public/assets/pics/" + card.cardId + ".png");
            require("http").get(card.img, (res) => {
                res.pipe(img);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your process exits before the downloads are finished. The http.get functions runs in parallel so you need to handle that in some way. You can use the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module to do that.

```
function d() {
var data = [
    {
        img: "http://wow.zamimg.com/images/hearthstone/cards/enus/original/OG_134.png",
        cardId: "yogg"
    },
    {
        img: "http://wow.zamimg.com/images/hearthstone/cards/enus/original/HERO_07.png",
        cardId: "nzoth"
    }
];
var async = require('async')
async.each(data, (card, next) => {
    if("img" in card) {
        var img = require('fs').createWriteStream(card.cardId + ".png");
          require("http").get(card.img, (res) => {
              res.pipe(img).on('end', next)
          });
    }
}
, () => {
  console.log(done)
})
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    request = require('request');

var download = function(uri, filename, callback){
  request.head(uri, function(err, res, body){
    console.log('content-type:', res.headers['content-type']);
    console.log('content-length:', res.headers['content-length']);

    request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback);
  });
};

download('https://www.THE_URL.com/image.png', 'THE_NAME.png', function(){
  console.log('Image saved!');
});
```